# Dual Phantom Power sources?

Tags: mixer, power, phantom

I have a question if anyone would be kind enough to answer. I have a phantom power on my mixer and my sound card. I have only ever used the phantom supply on the mixer because that is where the mic is plugged into directly. I am curious though, would it be better to use the phantom power supply from the soundcard? Is that even possible if the mic is running through the mixer? Should/could I have them both on? I tried googling but couldn't find any info on which is better or using two. 
Basically I was having some issues with excess noise when recording vocals and I thought this might make a difference changing the phantom power supply but didn't want to hurt my condenser in the process. Would generally like to know anyway. Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

A

Answer (score 1):

No, if you're running your microphone in your mixer, and your mixer into your sound card, there is no way to use phantom power from your sound card.

It wouldn't hurt your microphone, because the phantom power would try to power the outputs of your mixer, but it could (if its a bad mixer) damage your outputs on the mixer.

If you think you're getting noise because of the mixer, why not just plug the microphone directly into the sound card? Using a mixer is entirely unnecessary if you're just recording in a predicted and controlled environment.

Comment: Using a mixer _could_ make sense if the sound card doesn't have latency-free monitoring. All halfway-decent soundcards have that, though... I agree, it's probably best to omit the mixer entirely.